# Why is the confirmation statement printing to the console twice?

Tags: java

Whenever I run the program, everything works fine but for some reason the Confirmation prints are happening twice and I can't figure out why. Any help would be appreciated.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String Z = "Z";
        int number;
        String Znumber = "";
        String Confirmation = "";
        int ExamType;

        // Ask user for Z number
        do {
            System.out.println("Please enter your Z number. Example: 12345678");
            number = input.nextInt();
            Znumber = Z + number;

        } while ((Znumber.length() != 9));

        //Confirm Z number entry
        do {
            System.out.printf(
                    "Your Z number is: %s. Is this correct? Enter Y/N: \n",
                    Znumber);
            Confirmation = input.nextLine();
        } while (!Confirmation.equalsIgnoreCase("y"));

        // Ask user which exam they would like to take
        ExamType = 0;
        Confirmation = "";

        System.out.println("Which exam would you like to take? Select 1-3: ");
        System.out.println("1: English");
        System.out.println("2: Spanish");
        System.out.println("3: Math");
        ExamType = input.nextInt();

        do {
            System.out.printf("You selected %s. Are you sure? Enter Y/N: \n",
                    ExamType);
            Confirmation = input.nextLine();

        } while (!Confirmation.equalsIgnoreCase("y"));

        // Begin exam
        if (ExamType == 1) {

            System.out.println("Welcome to the English exam!");
            // Start code from JavaExam.java

        } else if (ExamType == 2) {

            System.out.println("Welcome to the Spanish exam!");
            // Start code from MathExam.java

        } else if (ExamType == 3) {

            System.out.println("Welcome to the Math exam!");
            // Start code from EnglishExam.java
```

Comment: Which message do yo call "confirmation message"? "Your Z number is..." or "You selected %s. Are you sure?"

Comment: After you use `nextInt()` you need to call `nextLine()` to use up the rest of that input line. Otherwise `nextLine()` will immediately return its buffered input and your `do` loop will go to a second iteration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `Confirmation = input.nextLine();`, use `Confirmation = input.next();` and you should be good. Tested and confirmed.

You really don't need `nextLine` here in your do-while loop.

Comment: Correct answer. Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: @WillCrayger No problem buddy, and welcome to SO.

Answer (score 0):

Your first loop (`// Ask user for Z number`)

```
number = input.nextInt();
```

does not read the last `'\n'`.

I think you need to add a `nextLine()` in that loop.

Answer (score 0):

In your do-while when you run for the first time print `Your Z number is: %s. Is this correct? Enter Y/N:`. after that the condition `!Confirmation.equalsIgnoreCase("y")` is evaluated in this case gives `true` for this cause try to run the loop do-while in second time.

```
     do {
       System.out.printf("Your Z number is: %s. Is this correct? Enter Y/N: \n",
               ....
        } while (!Confirmation.equalsIgnoreCase("y"));
```